# Is there any way to prevent an Xbox Controller from opening Windows Magnifier?

Tags: pc, controllers, windows

I'm using an Xbox controller on PC and I find that there's some particular button combination (something + the guide button) that launches the Windows Magnifier accessibility ("ease of access") feature. Disabling the feature doesn't prevent the controller from just enabling it again, however, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to prevent the shortcut from being triggered by the controller.

Comment: Are you using Steam?

Comment: @Joachim yes, Steam is running, but the game I'm playing isn't through Steam / overlay isn't up

Comment: Still, can you try exiting Steam and see if the problems persist? I've read that Steam often causes unwanted behaviour when using controllers.

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching for like 3 months, and what you do is the following:

1. Open the steam settings tab. You can find this in the top right of your steam window by clicking "Steam", then "Settings".

[image: Settings]

2. Navigate to the "Controller" tab, then press "Guide button chord configuration". A tab will open where you will see all of the guide button's actions.

[image: Controller tab]

3. Unbind or rebind actions as you like, in my case I've unbound all of the things because I had a problem where my right joystick kept spamming these actions, but if this feature actually works correctly for you, you can rebind things too!

[image]

I've been searching for ages for a solution so I had to share it with the world.

Comment: Wait, seriously? This is a thing? I have the oposite problem ... I'm partially blind and am SOOO sick of switching to my keyboard EVERY time I need Windows Magnifier? I can actually bind this in Steam settings? I am just ... stunned! Can anyone give me some directions how to do that properly? Dow I have a lead I'll likely figure it out, but you never know! Thank you!